# Angular JS Resource Post Parameter Defaulting to 0

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble figuring out how tho pass parameters to a web service using the POST method. The following UserId parameter shows up as 0 on the web service, because it is not receiving any parameters.

```
angular.module('Users').factory('UserFactories', function ($resource) {
   return {
       userSave: $resource('Service.svc/SaveDetail', { UserId: '@2' }, { query: { method: 'POST'} }),
   };
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the service expecting `service.svc/SaveDetails/2`. Also why change the query method, why not use the `save`, `update` methods already available. Where are you invoking it? `@2` means your object has a property with name `2`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
var User = $resource('Service.svc/SaveDetail');
var newUser = new User({ UserId: '@2' }); //guessing you should put a real value here instead of @2
newUser.$save();
// POST: /Service.svc/SaveDetail {UserId:'@2'}
```

You can refer to the credit card example of the $resource [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)